# How to force two discriminated unions to have the same type for their discriminator property?

Tags: typescript

My use case is the following:

```
type Discriminator = "one" | "two";

type OneTypeA = {
  type: "one",
  one: 1
}

type TwoTypeA = {
  type: "two",
  two: 2,
}

type TypeA = OneTypeA | TwoTypeA;

type OneTypeB = {
  type: "one",
  one: "unu"
}

type TwoTypeB = {
  type: "two",
  two: "du",
}

type TypeB = OneTypeB | TwoTypeB;
```

In my example, `TypeA` and `TypeB` are discriminated by the same type, however, this is not enforced (`Discriminator` is not used anywhere), thus it'd be possible for anyone to come and add any type to these unions that doesn't match the `Discriminator`. Is there any way I could enforce this?

My closest solution would be to have something like

```
type DiscriminatorRequired<T> = T extends { type: Discriminator } ? T : never;
type TypeA = DiscriminatorRequired<OneTypeA | TwoTypeA>
type TypeB = DiscriminatorRequired<OneTypeB | TwoTypeB>
```

However, this only filters out the types that don't match which is confusing and suboptimal. I'd prefer that this wasn't able to compile with an error indicating that the type must have a `type` property of type `Discriminator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just constrain the generic itself:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgZwMYCc4Fs4DsCGwD2KUAvFAET5YRlQA+5wA7vmQNwBQ7okUA8lQBVwEAIIkoAb3ZQo3CAC5ylahxnLFARg4BfDl2FQBzIZDGkpMuYrJMWq2c0UAmHXrmGAFiggQTo8RaywtbAXj5s0rJhClAAzK6c7gDClAjAKDjYEAAmADwCUBAAHsAQWNkIkkGQivDIaJi4BETaAHziAm4GfiK8ANbiKVhpGVl5-L7CYvRG+D2trFAA9EtQ+H36PD0AcvjA-YOp6ZlU44JTdIbGFzPR84tLAFSRMq9v7x+fUAB6v3--AMBQP+7D8UAA5BMepdZtDbt5JqZwVBsvgIJUsHsoAg8IgAGYgKLQJBHUZYYAQiTVGJ1VAYbB4QiLbTggB0kTB4IEdymyMQUExFJwCAQcAA5rgAEYAG2gBGplOptUQdMajJQzLZL0Mwkq+DxUDAKHwkBQoAhcmROG8UGwJPQYFxMog7I+nJs0TIfIxWOFoolOGdsnwCvBtIaDOabIAFE5YgAWeMASigjyW7CAA)

```ts
type Discriminator = "one" | "two";

type OneTypeA = {
  type: "one";
  one: 1;
};

type TwoTypeA = {
  type: "two";
  two: 2;
};

type ThreeTypeA = {
  type: "three";
  three: 3;
};

type Constrained<T extends { type: Discriminator }> = T;

type TypeAOk = Constrained<OneTypeA | TwoTypeA>; // ok
type TypeANotOk = Constrained<OneTypeA | TwoTypeA | ThreeTypeA>; /*
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Type 'OneTypeA | TwoTypeA | ThreeTypeA' does not satisfy the constraint '{ type: Discriminator; }'.
  Type 'ThreeTypeA' is not assignable to type '{ type: Discriminator; }'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type '"three"' is not assignable to type 'Discriminator'.(2344) */
```

Comment: So simple, I'm ashamed of not coming up with it myself

Comment: @Haf I bet you would have with more time!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is a nice, simple constraint on the `type` property, but you could also fully constrain the types and avoid hardcoding every type using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFUBcEsBtsgT1AFUQBwKYGcCwAoJLVDTAEWmwGMAnaAW2gDsBDSTAEwGVmBzWTAAUaAeyw0kAJUxURNDgB4K1Oo1aQ5oTAA92TDtlDZIdJrwA0oALIt0W3Zn2Hps+QuOmLoFk0QA+P1AAXlAAbwJQSNAAbQBpTGRmUGVaBmY2OQBdAC4wokxc+MQAX1AAMlAXOUUiyxt0OITMvwJi6JTVdI0aTIBuAgIQZMpUtQyaAnzhlTT1TRCAIhEmTAXQAB9QBcgAdxEF-vxBsABBEnQ+PEJSUBO0YhD78hHO9U4eMwFhMUwJRCq3B1ZuNLOF8FEtstVrkAIzmCJRbZ7Ba5ABM8PBiMgAAsaJhoaAAMygIYAMTg7DxHFAIgArpBQAAjZAAcieQLG7G4fC+onEUhk1RZrT8hyGoCmdxuIQAFGDxZF8rklisDsdIqUKgDFCrVpYYX4AJQbdWgOWmxWkZW7fZisCgTWVQVuJH7Syoo0DfCyJjGGkrKVYXKBzDBMIIy1B0AsqEsjEQqGw1qHH1+m0h4NPMNgiFK6M2uMRiV7NHJr2phk4vGYDO3LMhHNRPMsqv4wv4cUAPW7ndNWZZ21x+IWLNAlFATBEDJY2Gw0F4rEZAglIglNwHULWm1dI4AdEXWwUiWXvcs-SxYLBayHswerdHY-GoonQHCDyXQKjTT2e3316E1yjXUDn9I8YV6YsRFyJhaXoRlfgg4pR3HSdp1nedF2XDRANDFkQxZfcO3tSIAHlGQAKxkBl4EpC9QHoFhkGWWBkGwLAqGgAAzZAAGtJx2JhQHQPlfhgHBLB8akWz2UcOBEHAJynexKAZJIphZAC82AxDyidVwdU3fU-AIk8vSGAAhc5LkmG5zPrc5nhmTl3h5IQRL+bUlBeYFulBItgOVWkmAWJ9Ih3ZUOFpBYRTtSNQzs6UzXlYicOVTdYodXTPOAywFiChYjRNIjInNYqm3vHcMsdbKbRCrZIoKw1yzPBkoQSqN2tDBs7yjGMVnbXMPxZSLhTKn9xr-YgNNSyFVQgm1cg8PhEOQwxUO8dCFxYJdQ2w9TOpMsrSIoqjQBo346IYpimBYox2K43j+ME4SfgkaBxO8fR8xk0A5IU9adBUsdBPUzSKvSzKtWdAzVVy-LjMI4oUxayDOtyTrb0xOLcmkkQBqbIaRtM09fUrIdMDR0AMe6rGZtx-HFXJnGTBEShRq7cbOe7SbcLBoDavmpmjBMZaHVWxS0LnLadpXHDowOwiFVAMjKKoaiEAu2B6MY-1brYmQHtAPiRAEoT3LE7AJK+ltydk+S1qUwG-TU-8ZsqyG9OqBQd1yhqEZPIA)

###### Utility

```
type TypeDiscriminatedSinglePropertyRecord<Discriminator extends string, Map extends Record<string, any>> = {
    [Key in Discriminator]: {type: Key} & Record<Key, Map[Key]>
}[Discriminator];
```

###### Discriminator

```
type Discriminator = "one" | "two";
```

###### A Types

```
type AType = TypeDiscriminatedSinglePropertyRecord<Discriminator, {
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    "three": 3 // Filtered out by 'TypeDiscriminatedSinglePropertyRecord'
}>;
//  type AType = ({
//    type: "one";
//  } & Record<"one", 1>) |
//  ({
//    type: "two";
//  } & Record<"two", 2>)

const oneAType: AType = {
    type: 'one',
    one: 1
};
const twoAType: AType = {
    type: 'two',
    two: 2
};

const threeAType: AType = {
    type: 'three',
//  ^^^^
//  Type '"three"' is not assignable to type '"one" | "two"'.
    three: 3
};
const allAType: AType = {
    type: 'one',
    one: 1,
    two: 2
//  ^^^^^^
//  Type '{ type: "one"; one: 1; two: number; }' is not assignable to type 'AType'.
//    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'two' does not exist in type '{ type: "one"; } & Record<"one", 1>'.
};
```

###### B Types

```
type BType = TypeDiscriminatedSinglePropertyRecord<Discriminator, {
    "one": "un",
    "two": "du"
}>;
//  type BType = ({
//    type: "one";
//  } & Record<"one", "un">) |
//  ({
//    type: "two";
//  } & Record<"two", "du">)

const oneBType: BType = {
    type: 'one',
    two: 'du'
//  ^^^^^^^^^
//  Type '{ type: "one"; two: string; }' is not assignable to type 'BType'.
//    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'two' does not exist in type '{ type: "one"; } & Record<"one", "un">'.
};
const twoBType: BType = {
    type: 'two',
    two: 'du'
};

const threeBType: BType = {
    type: 'two',
    three: 'trois'
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  Type '{ type: "two"; three: string; }' is not assignable to type 'BType'.
//    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'three' does not exist in type '{ type: "two"; } & Record<"two", "du">'.
};
```